# Using MPI_Send/Recv to handle chunk of multi-dim array in Fortran 90

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, fortran90

I have to send and receive (MPI) a chunk of a multi-dimensional array in FORTRAN 90. The line

```
MPI_Send(x(2:5,6:8,1),12,MPI_Real,....)
```

is not supposed to be used, as per the book "Using MPI..." by Gropp, Lusk, and Skjellum. What is the best way to do this? Do I have to create a temporary array and send it or use `MPI_Type_Create_Subarray` or something like that?

Comment: Does the book give any reason for why you should use it? Is it saying it's bad? Or is it saying there's a better alternative?

Comment: Well, according to this book (which is one of the main ref books), the  present MPI 2 implementation does not necessarily obey FORTRAN 90's array syntax and forms. It does however show some methods but does not mention anything about MPI_Type_Create_Subarray, which I think is safer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason not to use array sections with `MPI_SEND` is that the compiler has to create a temporary copy with *some* MPI implementations. This is due to the fact that Fortran can only properly pass array sections to subroutines with explicit interfaces and has to generate temporary "flattened" copies in all other cases, usually on the stack of the calling subroutine. Unfortunately in Fortran before the TR 29113 extension to F2008 there is no way to declare subroutines that take variable type arguments and MPI implementations usually resort to language hacks, e.g. `MPI_Send` is entirely implemented in C and relies on Fortran always passing the data as a pointer.

Some MPI libraries work around this issue by generating huge number of overloads for `MPI_SEND`:

- one that takes a single `INTEGER`
- one that takes an 1-d array of `INTEGER`
- one that takes an 2-d array of `INTEGER`
- and so on

The same is then repeated for `CHARACTER`, `LOGICAL`, `DOUBLE PRECISION`, etc. This is still a hack as it does not cover cases where one passes user-defined type. Further it greatly complicates the C implementation as it now has to understand the Fortran array descriptors, which are very compiler-specific.

Fortunately times are changing. The TR 29113 extension to Fortran 2008 includes two new features:

- assumed-type arguments: `TYPE(*)`
- assumed-dimension arguments: `DIMENSION(..)`

The combination of both, i.e. `TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..), INTENT(IN) :: buf`, describes an argument that can both be of varying type and have any dimension. This is already being taken advantage of in the new `mpi_f08` interface in MPI-3.

Non-blocking calls present bigger problems in Fortran that go beyond what Alexander Vogt has described. The reason is that Fortran does not have the concept of suppressing compiler optimisations (i.e. there is no `volatile` keyword in Fortran). The following code might not run as expected:

```
INTEGER :: data

data = 10
CALL MPI_IRECV(data, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, req, ierr)
! data is not used here
! ...
CALL MPI_WAIT(req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
! data is used here
```

One might expect that after the call to `MPI_WAIT` `data` would contain the value received from rank 0, but this might very well not be the case. The reason is that the compiler cannot know that `data` might change asynchronously after `MPI_IRECV` returns and therefore keep its value in a register instead. That's why non-blocking MPI calls are generally considered as dangerous in Fortran.

TR 29113 has solution for that second problem too with the `ASYNCHRONOUS` attribute. If you take a look at the `mpi_f08` definition of `MPI_IRECV`, its `buf` argument is declared as:

```
TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..), INTENT(OUT), ASYNCHRONOUS :: buf
```

Even if `buf` is a scalar argument, i.e. no temporary copy is created, a TR 29113 compliant compiler would not resort to register optimisations for the buffer argument.

Comment: Actually, Fortran 2003 does have `volatile`, but the asynchronous should be indeed much better here.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As Hristo Iliev pointed out `MPI_Send` is always blocking, but might choose to send data asynchronously. From [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/sendmode.html):

> MPI_Send will not return until you can use the send buffer.

Non-blocking communications (like `MPI_Send`), might pose a problem with Fortran when non-contiguous arrays are involved. Then, the compiler creates a temporary array for the dummy variable and passes it to the subroutine. Once the subroutine is finished, the compiler is at liberty to free the memory of that copy.

That's fine as long as you use blocking communication (`MPI_Send`), because then the message has been sent when the subroutine returns. For the non-blocking communication (`MPI_Isend`), however, the temporary array is the send buffer, and the subroutine returns *before* it has been sent.

So it might happen, that MPI will send data from a memory location that holds no valid data any more.

So, either you create a copy yourself (so that your send buffer is contiguous in memory), or you create a sub-array (i.e. tell MPI the addresses in memory of elements you want to send). There are further alternatives out there, like `MPI_Pack`, but I have no experience with them.

Which way is faster? Well, that depends:

- On the actual implementation of your MPI library
- On the data and its distribution
- On your compiler
- On your hardware

See [here](http://grl.public.iastate.edu/MPI.Derived.Types.Yanmei.April14.2005.doc) for a detailed explanation and further options.

Comment: You are confusing blocking with synchronous. `MPI_Send` might not be always synchronous, but it is **always blocking** and after it returns it never again accesses the data parameter. Your explanation is only valid for calls such as `MPI_Isend`.